# C++ issue with polymorphism base and inherited class instantiation

Tags: c++, polymorphism, virtual

I have a basic base class and a couple of sub-classes which inherit from it.

```
Class Base{
public:
   Base(){};
   virtual ~Base();
   virtual void foomethod()=0; //Marked as pure virtual
};

Class A : public Base{
   A(){};  //Ctor
   ~A(){}; //Dtor
   void foomethod(){ /* DO SOMETHING */ }
}
Class B : public Base{
   B(){};  //Ctor
   ~B(){}; //Dtor
   void foomethod(){ /* DO SOMETHING */ }
}
```

Use of the above is throwing an error in the following usage:

```
Base a = A();
Base b = B();
```

The compiler is complaining about the function `foomethod()` being pure virtual.

However, when the following is used, there is no problem.

```
A a = A();
B b = B();
```

I would have thought that the first instance should be accepted due to C++'s principles of polymorphism. I want to enforce a specific method implementation of the method in sub-classes. If it is marked as virtual only, there is not guarantee that it will be explicitly overrided.

Comment: First, that easily leads to slicing. Second, you can't create an object of an abstract base class.

Comment: You can't instantiate an object with a pure method directly (no code for that). And virtual polymorphism works with pointers, see the slicing problem here as chris noted

Comment: Useful text on SO about this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c

Comment: @MarcoA., Pointers and references.

Comment: @chris Right, thanks! They also use pointers internally (but that is hardly something relevant here)

Answer (score 3):

There are several issues with your code, I'll try to get most of them:

1. You can't have a pure function without marking it as virtual
2. You can't create objects of an abstract `Base` class (there's no code for the methods)
3. When you write

   ```
   Base b = A();
   ```

   you're creating two objects and then assigning the A object to the `Base b` object. This cannot happen since Base is abstract but in cases where this can happen you could experience the [slicing problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c).
4. You marked the destructor as virtual in the derived classes but not in the `Base` (and no definition either), always mark it as `virtual` when using virtual polymorphism otherwise derived destructors will not be called

This is a more correct way of doing it:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Base{
public:
   Base(){};
   virtual ~Base() {};
   virtual void foomethod()=0; //Marked as pure virtual
};

class A : public Base{
public: 
   A(){};  //Ctor
   virtual ~A(){}; //Dtor
   void foomethod(){ cout << "Hello from A"; }
};
class B : public Base{
public:
   B(){};  //Ctor
   virtual ~B(){}; //Dtor
   void foomethod(){ /* DO SOMETHING */ }
};

int main() {

    // Base obj; // Can't do that
    Base *obj = new A();
    obj->foomethod(); // A's one
    delete obj;

    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/gvcL9S

Oh and there were some syntax errors here and there.. and a visibility problem if you intend to use those functions from the outside.. but I believe the excerpt was just a pseudocode one.

Comment: FWIW, you could implement `foomethod` so there is code for it and still not be able to succeed :)

Comment: Would be better if the solution didn't rely on error-prone new and delete. Unfortunately pointers are polymorphic but objects aren't. The answer might be found in something templated.

Comment: @RafaelCamposNunes: I think that would just drift even further away from the purpose of the original question.